# Should I say "'In' which floor are you living in /on "?

Tags: prepositions

What is the better way to ask person which floor is he living in / on?

> 1. Which floor are living **in**?
> 2. Which floor are living **on**?
> 3. **In** which floor are living in?
> 4. **In** which floor are living on?

Comment: I think you mean "floor", perhaps?

Comment: @DamkerngT. - unless it's a sentence about worms speaking to each other, I guess you're right. If it's about worms, it might be better to say "which sack of flour".

Comment: One does not live on bread alone. lol.

Comment: I changed "flour" to "floor".

Comment: No need to repeat a preposition. Strand it at the end, **or** pied-pipe it to the beginning. **Don't** do both.

Comment: I wouldn't say *in*, unless I was talking to a termite.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If my friend lived on a college campus like this one:

[image]

then I would ask:

- Which building do you live **in**?
- Which floor do you live **on**?
- Which room do you live **in**?

If the university had more than one campus (say, an east campus and a west campus), then I might begin with:

- Which campus do you live **on**?

Comment: Why "Which campus do you live on?" and no "Which campus do you live in?" ?

Comment: @AmitSingh - Assuming the two campuses are geographically seperated, I would use _live on_ for last question (AmE speaker). It's odd, though, isn't it? I would ask, "Which town do you live in?" but, "Which campus do you live on?" I don't know why, but that's just [the way it seems to be](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+campus%2Cin+campus%2C+on+the+campus%2C+in+the+campus&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15).

Comment: It is ODD. But seems like we have to live with it.

Comment: @AmitSingh Floors are always under you; you're not contained by them.  A room or building surrounds you.  You stand ON top of the floor, but IN a room (or cell, or box).  A campus is a piece of land, which again is usually under your feet (ignoring tunnels and basements) so again you're on the campus.

Comment: @Andy: By that logic I live ON India? Sounds ODD again.

Comment: @AmitSingh Nobody said English was consistent, but in general what I said holds.  Just like living on a street doesn't mean you actually live ON the street, it means adjacent.

Comment: @Andy - I can't agree with your rationalization of why we're "on campus" – I don't think we live "on campus" because we're standing on top of it. The preposition _on_ doesn't just mean "on top of"; it has a handful of other meanings, too. Besides _on campus,_ we have _on a roll, on a trip, on the telephone, on the radio, on Friday, on drugs,_ and _on fire_. The definition that applies here is stated in NOAD as _located somewhere in the general surface area of_ – that's one of about two dozen defintions of _on_.

Comment: @J.R. None of your examples use a physical location as the noun.  Context is a requirement to understanding language, and the rules of the language can and do change based on the context.  When using on in combination with a location, what I said generally stands.  And physical proximity to the actual ground matters; you're not on campus if you're directly over it but in a plane, and you only can live on campus if you sleep on the ground or something directly on the ground.  You can't live on campus if you live in a structure that hovers 10000 feet over campus at all times.

Comment: @Andy: But you *can* live on campus, even if you live on the 17th floor of your dormitory. No one would say you're living "above campus" in that case. Anyhow, my point was that your logic ("A campus is a piece of land, therefore you're *on* the campus") is flawed and oversimplfied. When it comes to locations, sometimes we're on, and sometimes we're in, and sometimes we're at. We can live *in* a nation, and *in* a city, but *on* an island, *on* a beach, *on* a farm, or *on* a campus. Some of it's idiomatic: Interesting how we we live *in* a world but *on* a planet.

Comment: @J.R. A building on campus is touching the ground, which is what i said.  If the building were hovering 5000 ft above campus, i'd argue you're not living on campus, just like you're not on campus if you're in a plane over it.  And yes I've already acknowledged that my statement doesn't always hold, but it often does, i never claimed it was 100%.

Comment: Although if you want to argue, since nations and cities also include some of the airspace above them (you're still subject to state law in a plane flying over the state), my 3d vs 2d argument holds there.  World is a fairly general word and could include the atmosphere (thus you being in the world) while planet doesn't necessarily include atmosphere (since many planets exist without).

Comment: @Andy - I'm not trying to argue. I was only addressing this your "piece of land, therefore _on_" comment. I thought that could be misleading to a learner. It's just not that simple, and English learners struggle with prepositions – a lot. One of my most upvoted answers on ELU (pre-ELL) was just trying to explain when we sit _on_ a chair, and when we sit _in_ a chair. Prepositions are vexing and tricky, and oversimpllified (or overly complicated) reasons as to why and when we use them deserve a caveat. I mean, airspace? The atmosphere? Really? You think about that when choosing a preposition?

Comment: @J.R. Ya, i never said it was simple, i said in general it can work, and then i said English is inconsistent.  I don't think about prepositions at all, having been raised speaking English.  But for someone trying to learn, a general rule, even if not 100%, is more helpful then trying to learn every single nuance all at once.  And i'll point out that you (probably) and I were taught English the same way in school, with general rules, and then learning the exceptions.

Comment: @Andy - Then it sounds like we're agreeing more than we're arguing. :-) Sometimes these things have a simple explanation, and sometimes they don't. If anything, I hope the learner can read through this dialog and realize that even native speakers can sometimes be puzzled about why things are said the way they are.

Answer (score 8):

I think because "a **floor**" is [originally] ***a surface***, you can't live "**in**" it, only "**on**" it.

Same goes to "**level**", for instance.  A "**level**" is [originally] ***a measure***, the **distance** from the base point or plane.  Since a representation of such a measure would be another plane or a sphere (if measured from a point), in other word a surface, it has no thickness, and only allows being "**on**" it, not "**in**" it for such three-dimensional beings like humans.

So,

> Which floor do you live **on**? (*or*)
>   **On** which floor do you live? (*so not to end on a preposition*)

Comment: Your logic is sound, but we need to be careful trying to make these prepositions seem so straightforward. They're not. For example, you can live "on Elm Street" – but that doesn't mean you live on the surface of the street. Also, you might live in a house that's "on the water," even though that really means "on a parcel of land within view of the water." One more: You could live "on the Polish-Ukrainian border," but that would probably mean you live _along_ the border, not physically _on_ it, with the east side of your apartment in the Ukraine, and the west side of your apartment in Poland.

Comment: Right.  Everything is relative.  One lives **on** the border, when the distance between his house and the border is small enough compared to the rest of the population's.

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct one would be..

On which floor are you living ?
Which floor do you live on ?

There is no need to use in/or twice in the same sentence.
On is used more often when talking about living on floors.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of asking someone which floor they live on:
"Which floor are you living on?" or "Which floor do you live on?"

More natural:
"Which floor are you on?"

Answer (score -1):

I would say, "What floor do you live on?"  is more casual.  "On what floor do you live on?" works, but it sounds a bit "off".

Comment: "On what floor do you live?"  - Overly formal, but correct. "On what floor do you live on?" - wrong.

Comment: It sounds off because the two instances of 'on' are redundant.